# How to cache API JSON response in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, caching, tastypie

i'm new in tastypie REST for django, i use the property cache in my ModelResource but don't work, when i making changes to the database and refresh the API url `http://localhost:8000/api/rest/tip/` this shows the last changes, this information does not need to constantly refresh

```
class TipResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tip.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'tip'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = False
        cache = SimpleCache(timeout=1000)
```

I need to cache this response for not making many queries to the database

What can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Tastypie's SimpleCache will cache single resource fetches, but will not cache queries.  It's very limited.  So /api/rest/tip/< TIP_ID >/ will get cached, but any requests that require a query will not.

The easiest way to cache your result is to enable Django's view caching.  In that case, Django will just cache the serialized JSON result, and return that until the cache times out.  Tastypie won't even see the request.

However, be careful, since Django's caching uses HTTP caching, so the browser could cache the data and not issue a request to your server at all.  If your data changes, you're pretty much screwed in this case.

A proper solution is a bit more complicated, and not included with Tastypie.  I've actually worked on this not too long ago.  See my message in the tastypie group, though I haven't seen anyone else interested in a solution yet:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/django-tastypie/87mlo7bvCgo

Comment: Does that message has followups? can't believe there is no interest whatsoever...

Comment: Never had a followup.  I believe that the problem with invalidating the cache for arbitrary queries is pretty much impossible, so it's not handled.  If you only use specific queries, you'll have to handle the cache invalidation yourself manually.

Answer (score 1):

you could override the function `get_list` in `tastypie.resources.ModelResource`
change the code `objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle,**self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))` to `objects=self.cached_obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle,**self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))`

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)

    objects = self.cached_obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

    sorted_objects = self.apply_sorting(objects, options=request.GET)

    paginator = self._meta.paginator_class(request.GET, sorted_objects, resource_uri=self.get_resource_uri(), limit=self._meta.limit, max_limit=self._meta.max_limit, collection_name=self._meta.collection_name)
    to_be_serialized = paginator.page()

    # Dehydrate the bundles in preparation for serialization.
    bundles = []

    for obj in to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name]:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=obj, request=request)
        bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle, for_list=True))

    to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name] = bundles
    to_be_serialized = self.alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, to_be_serialized)

    return self.create_response(request, to_be_serialized)
```

then /api/rest/tip/ will get cached,not only /api/rest/tip/< TIP_ID >/